# c# - Turning a variable for a List Item

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I'm having another issue here. I have a class and a List for my Purchasers:

```
public class Purchaser
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool Paid { get; set; }
}

List<Purchaser> Purchasers = new List<Purchaser>();
```

I also have a code to add new purchasers by cathing the text from one textbox and adding it to the Purchaser List and to my listbox **listDOF**:

```
if(box_AddPerson.TextLength != 0)
{
    Purchaser purchaser = new Purchaser();
    purchaser.Name = caixa_AddJog.Text;
    purchaser.Paid = true;
    listDOF.Items.Add(purchaser.Name);
    Purchasers.Add(purchaser);
 }
```

Ok, now I want be able to assign the variable **Paid** for each purchaser using a checkbox, but I really do not know how to do this. I've searched but found nothing.
According to the selected purchaser in the listbox, I want be able to change his variable, by checking or unchecking the checkbox. I tried this:

```
private void box_Paid_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (box_Paid.Checked == true)
    {
        Purchaser p = new Purchaser(listDOF.SelectedIndex);
        p.Paid = true;
    }
}
```

But this is not working. Can anyone give me a hand? Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this instead:

```
private void box_Paid_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (box_Paid.Checked == true)
    {
        Purchaser p = Purchasers[listDOF.SelectedIndex];
        p.Paid = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I would add is that you wanted to be able to set true or false - make the last line 'p.Paid = box_Paid.Checked' and eliminate the if...???

Comment: I was trying by the same way, but with the wrong syntax. He showed me how to do this correctly.

Comment: @user54321 I'm having an exception when I try to remove one purchaser from the listbox.
The exception says: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."
Is caused by the `Purchaser p = Purchasers[listDOF.SelectedIndex]` line.
This exception is trowed when I'm using this code also in the event `private void listDOF_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: @Hypister: you could try to check with `if (listDOF.SelectedIndex>=0)` before accessing the list

Comment: @user54321 haha' perfectly again. Thanks dude, you're the best! :)